# Does it make sense to create a class to represent the stock of a store?

Tags: c++, class, oop

I'm new to OOP and I'm trying to create a program. Basically it's a store and it has products and clients and all that stuff. However, I'm struggling with a question.

When it comes to OOP, does it make sense to create a class to represent the stock of the products? Something like:

```
class Stock
{
private:
    Product *_product;
    int _nrOfProducts;

    ...

};
```

I'm asking because initially I had thought about it being an atribute of the product but then I started wondering things like "What if I delete a product? All of its information will be lost - including the stock, which I still need".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Another question would be: Should you be able to delete a product, especially when you still have stock for that product? Should you be able to delete it at all, since historic information (orders, invoices) might depend on in. I've seen another shop implementation where a product may be made inactive, but can never be deleted.

Comment: What language is this in? Add the tag to your question.

Comment: @GolezTrol, thank you, what you said made a lot of sense in my head!

Comment: @Sam, I didn't put because it was a question related to the OOP concept and not implementation. It's C++, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of tutorials will tell you otherwise, but in general objects are better at modeling abstractions in your software that capture behavior rather than modelling objects in the physical world. That's just data, whereas an object or better yet an interface is about capturing and abstracting behavior that can vary depending upon the situation.

As to the decision to cache the number of products v.s. not. The typical answer is, "It depends." Frequently you won't need to, because you'll be using a more sophisticated collection type that gives you an easy "count" operation. You might need that stored separately for some other reason though.